# Is there a way to add a new record to store dynamically in Extjs 6.2?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I've been using **Ext.js 4.2** and when I adding a new record to store it adds it dynamically(right away) to my grid when simply doing:

```
me.getStore().insert(0, rec);
```

But when I use **Extjs 6.2** it adds it to the store but **DOES NOT** show it in the grid right away. So my question is: Is there a way to add a new record to store dynamically (right away) and show it in the grid in Ext.js 6.2? 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: could you share a fiddle? https://fiddle.sencha.com

Comment: @Edwin This application is Huge and it's kind of hard to put it in fiddle. Basically when I use the developer tools and step over each line I see that when adding a new record it adds it to the store BUT doesn't show it in the grid when using version 6.2, but if I use version 4.2 it adds it right away to both (the store and grid)

Comment: @Edwin do you know another way to insert a new record to store and show it in the grid right away? Thanks!

Comment: without the code it is hard to tell what can be wrong in your code. You can try other methods like http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/modern/Ext.data.Store.html#method-loadData

Comment: Is it possible that you have a filter on the store?  It shouldn't be necessary, but you can refresh the grid view in a [dataChanged](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/modern/Ext.data.ArrayStore.html#event-datachanged) listener event handler on the store.

Comment: @chrisuae can you add a quick example on what you mean and post it as an answer please? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your code, it's difficult to know what may be causing this. See example fiddle [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/298i) to demonstrate some possibilities.

If you just click on the `Add Row` button, your row will be added to the store and appear in the grid.

If you have a `filter` set on the store and the new record does not match the filter, you will not see your new record in the grid. To demo this, run the fiddle again and first click on the `Add Filter` button and then `Add Row`.  Your record will be added to the store but will not appear in the grid because it doesn't match the filter.

In the example, the idProperty on the model is `name` so the values in this property must be unique.  If you add a record with the same idProperty as an existing record (run fiddle again and click on `add another` button), the existing record will go into the `removed` array on the store and will no longer show in the grid.

Comment: do you know how to access all the ID's of each grid in the accordion? Can you please help me on that one? Here's the link I posted on that question? Thank you so much! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47115108/how-to-access-the-id-of-a-collapsetool-in-a-grid