# How to access the ID of a collapseTool in a grid?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs5

I'm trying to access the ID of the **collapseTool** in a grid, but I'm not having any luck. Here's a pic of my console when I simply console out the grid.

```
console.log(grid);
```

[image]

and I would like to get the Id **tool-1782**

I've tried:

```
 console.log(grid.collapseTool)
```

but it prints

> undefined

I'm working with an accordion that has grids inside of it, and I would like to get the id of each collapse button.

**Example:**

```
 1) Id of first button: tool-1782
 2) Id of second button: tool-1783
 3) Id of third button: tool-1784
 4) Id of fourth button: tool-1785
 ......
 ....
```

**Here's a picture of my accordion.**

[image]

Does anyone know how to access the id of collapseTool in a grid? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have used same `console.log(grid.collapseTool.getId())` it is working fine.

You check here on my [sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/298r) demo.

Here, Also you can check [how-to-have-reference-to-an-accordin-in-extjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47105639/how-to-have-reference-to-an-accordin-in-extjs/47110177#47110177).

Comment: Can you please update your code without using a controller? just make it a very simple accordion with grids inside and output the ID's. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Here is I have created an [sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2997) without controller. You can see how is working.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help bro!! Voting it up and accepted answer :)

Comment: Note that `collapseTool` isn't part of the API.

Comment: always welcome. Yes `collapseTool` not mentioned in ExtJS doc api.

Comment: If you want to avoid going outside the documented API, you can use `grid.down('tool').getId()` instead of `grid.collapseTool.getId()`.  See [Sencha docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.container.Container.html#method-down).

Comment: @chrisuae yes of course we can use as you mentioned `grid.down('tool').getId()`.